# AWS s3 GetObject operation: Access Denied for public bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied

So, I'm new to AWS, and I've been asked to download the files inside a public bucket.

But I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea of what may be causing this problem?

I'm really new to AWS, so don't assume I've done something that is obvious.

Comment: Are you sure that the bucket has correct public policy?

Comment: It is either the bucket is not public or your profile does not allow `s3:GetObject`!

Comment: @Marcin Actually, I don't have access to the policy, but I've been assured that yes :p

Comment: @franklinsijo, I'll check it out, do you have and article that could help me check if my profile allows getObject?

Comment: Do you know how your profile `raulw` is configured in the command line? Does it have a role specified or just access keys?

Comment: it does have access keys, but I'm not sure if it has a role, and if it does, the role allows to run getObject. Im away of my computer now, but as soon as I get back to it, I will send a print of the content of the files in the .aws folder, hope it helps :p

Comment: If it is just access keys, it will have an IAM user associated with it. You can check the Policy attached to the user. If you have access to the console, you can get that information from IAM.

Comment: @franklinsijo I updated my question with the policy that i edited in my user, and run in the policy simulator, there shows the result. I tried that same command in my question again but the result was the same. Is it safe to assume is some issue with this S3 ACL?

Comment: You have full S3 Access. It is the bucket's permissions that is blocking. The bucket is not public-read.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to list the contents of that bucket with:

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://geofusion-insights-public/
```

However, I am *not* able to download any of the files. Therefore, the bucket has *not* been fully configured as "public".

The only way to download the objects would be to use credentials from the same AWS Account as the bucket itself, if those credentials are specifically granted permission to `GetObject` from that bucket.

So:

- If the bucket is owned by the same people who gave you the credentials, ask them to add `GetObject` permissions for that bucket to your credentials
- Otherwise, you'll need to ask the bucket owner to fix their Bucket Policy to allow anyone to `GetObject` from the bucket (if it was their intention to make it "public")